# Quando o objeto estará elegível para o GarbageCollector?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, garbage-collector

Dos trechos de código abaixo, em quais o objeto criado em `new Pessoa("João")` estará disponível para o *garbage collector* na linha: `//outras instruções` ?

São todos códigos independentes. Não estão na mesma classe ou arquivo.

**1**

```
public void algumMetodo() {
    AlgumaClasse algumaClasse = new AlgumaClasse();
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa("João");
    algumaClasse.printaNome(p);
    //outras instruções
}
```

---

**2**

```
public void algumMetodo() {
    AlgumaClasse algumaClasse = new AlgumaClasse();
    algumaClasse.printaNome(new Pessoa("João"));
    //outras instruções
}
```

---

**3**

```
public void algumMetodo() {
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa("João");
    new AlgumaClasse().printaNome(p);
    //outras instruções
}
```

---

**4**

```
public void algumMetodo() {
    new AlgumaClasse().printaNome(new Pessoa("João"));
    //outras instruções
}
```

---

**5**

```
public void algumMetodo() {
    AlgumaClasse.printaNomeStatic(new Pessoa("João"));
    //outras instruções
}
```

---

Métodos `printaNome` e `printaNomeStatic`:

```
public void printaNome(Pessoa p) {
    System.out.println(p.getNome());
}

public static void printaNomeStatic(Pessoa p) {
    System.out.println(p.getNome());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nas opções 2, 4 e 5. Nas outras o objeto continua referenciado e não poderá ser coletado ali. Possivelmente será coletado no final do método (se não escapar ele de alguma forma (colocar em outro objeto que que não é local ao método, outra *thread*, ou retornar, o que não ocorre ali porque é `void`).

Em 2, 4 e 5 o objeto é criado, passado para outro método (os que imprimem) que mantém uma referência para ele, e no seu fim não há mais referência já que no `algumMetodo()` não tem referência própria para esse objeto, aí já pode ser coletado.

A coleta sempre é **possível** quando não há mais referências. O início da coleta pode ocorrer em qualquer momento que tente fazer uma alocação e determine que falta espaço naquela arena da memória.

Comment: Por que não a 2 também?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli é, eu vi criando o objeto e armazenando em variável e achei que era ele que tinha sido enviado, não prestei atenção.