# O que o gerenciamento de memória do Java realiza em uma atribuição de uma variável já alocada na memória anteriormente?

Tags: java, gerenciamento-de-memória

Gostaria de entender melhor o que o gerenciamento de memória do Java realiza na seguinte situação.

Sabendo que estou sofrendo com problemas de performance, estou tentando tomar o máximo de cuidado para não deixar a situação ainda pior, nisso ocorreu a necessidade de realizar o seguinte método:

```
public List<List<Object>> getValues() throws DataNotFoundException {
    List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

    for (SurveyActivity surveyActivity : this.surveyActivities) {
        this.recordsFactory = new SurveyActivityExtractionRecordsFactory(this.surveyForm, this.headersFactory.getHeaders());            
        List<Object> resultInformation = new ArrayList<>();
        this.recordsFactory.getSurveyBasicInfo(surveyActivity);
        this.recordsFactory.getSurveyQuestionInfo(surveyActivity);
        resultInformation.addAll(new ArrayList<>(this.recordsFactory.getSurveyInformation().values()));
        values.add(resultInformation);          
    }
    return values;
}
```

Perceba que o atributo `recordsFactory` está recebendo uma nova instância para cada entrada no laço, essa tomada de decisão se deve, pois precisamos "limpar" a instância do objeto para cada entrada no laço, como o gerenciador de memória do Java irá lidar com essa situação?

Ele irá alocar esse novo objeto no mesmo espaço de memória anteriormente?

Sabendo que preciso "limpar" essa instância, existe uma alternativa melhor?

Existe algum artigo onde posso encontrar mais informações sobre como o gerenciador de memória trabalha?

Comment: Por que diz "(...) essa tomada de decisão se deve, pois precisamos "limpar" a instância do objeto para cada entrada no laço (...)". Pergunto porque parece-me que os valores passados ao construtor não se alteram durante o laço. Assim sendo,  o objecto **recordsFactory** instanciado tem um estado igual ao anterior("é sempre o mesmo"). A não ser que `getSurveyBasicInfo()` e `getSurveyQuestionInfo` alterem o estado o que seria "errado".

Comment: @ramaral dentro da classe SurveyActivityExtractionRecordsFactory existe um mapa com valores que para cada entrada no laço eu preciso garantir que não irá existir um lixo, utilizando a mesma instância, ocorria casos onde aparecia valores incorretos. Nesse momento então tomei a decisão de realizar um new para cada entrada no laço, minha dúvida acabou sendo se essa tomada de decisão acabou afetando a performance.

Comment: Sem conhecer a classe é difícil falar. No entanto parece-me que deveria repensar a sua implementação. O facto de ter métodos chamados `getQualquerCoisa` que retornam void é indicador de que algo poderia ser melhorado.

Comment: Algumas dúvidas ainda estão em branco, mas vou avaliar a sua resposta como positiva.

Comment: @Emanoel diga o que.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toda vez que usar um `new` está criando um novo objeto no *heap* (não sei se isto vai mudar em Java 10, que terá alocação no *stack*). É simples assim. E todo objeto novo será alocado onde for melhor naquele momento. É certo que será outro local e pressionará o coletor de lixo.

Se o objeto permitir e não precisa mais dos dados pode limpá-lo (zerar todos os dados, incluindo o grafo de objetos pendurado nele) em vez de criar um novo. Ou pelo menos trocar todos os seus dados, só cuidado para não deixar lixo do anterior. Em objetos complexos isto pode ser muito complicado.

Dependendo do caso pode-se pensar em um algoritmo completamente diferente.

De fato se tiver muitos itens para processar este algoritmo causará estrago na memória.

Algumas respostas não são sobre Java, mas ou é igual ou dá uma ideia:

- [O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101)
- [Por que o garbage collector do .NET possui várias gerações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200713/101)
- [Gerenciamento e liberação de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259882/101)
- [Por que chamar o System.gc() não garante execução do garbage collector?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/101)
- [Quando o objeto estará elegível para o GarbageCollector?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191765/101)
- [Qual a razão de Java consumir tanta memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52517/101)
- [Garbage collector é automático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204344/101)
- [Heap de memória Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36741/101)
- [Linguagem com Garbage Collector pode ser usada para jogos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205049/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que quer dizer com "limpá-lo"?

Comment: Zerar todos os dados do objeto. O que pode não ser possível.

Comment: Me lembrei que tenho que terminar uma resposta aí :)

Comment: É, volta e meia me lembro dela :)

Comment: Estou errado se disser que "Zerar(null) todos os dados do objeto." pouco alterará a pressão no colector, que até poderá por mais pressão?

Comment: Mas em uma atribuição como ocorreu acima, o objeto novo não irá ser guardado no mesmo espaço de memoria do objeto anterior?

Comment: No meu problema em particular, existe um mapa na classe SurveyActivityExtractionRecordsFactory que acaba ficando com lixo, caso eu venha utilizar a mesma instância. Quando você fala em limpar, sabendo que é um mapa de chave e valor, será que existe uma forma melhor de realizar esse procedimento do que dar um new para cada elemento?

Comment: @ramaral Não está, mas também está :) Depende. Primeiro nem sempre é possível zerar tudo, a API dele tem que deixar, lembre-se que tem coisas que você pode não ter acesso. Se o objeto é por valor não muda nada, se é por referência, não colocará mais pressão, comparando com sempre alocar um objeto novo, mas terá bem menos vantagens, porque uma parte do grafo de objetos contido nele continuará tendo nova alocação. Ou seja, é como o problema do `clone()`, pra clonar tudo (*deep*) precisa percorrer todo o grafo e lidar com os ciclos.

Comment: Não basta zerar só na superfície, teria que zerar, e não alocar novo em todo o grafo, e todos objetos precisam permitir isso para conseguir o ganho total. Ou seja, é complicado. Se a pessoa puder seria bom criar um objeto que lide com isso que seria como um *pool*. Pra aplicações triviais o GC é ótimo para as que precisam de otimização de memória eu tenho me convencido cada vez mais que o gerenciamento semiautomático com auxílio de boas ferramentas pode dar melhor resultado.

Comment: @Emanoel precisaria analisar com mais profundidade, realmente é um caso que complica um pouco, mas não sei te dizer o resultado sem testar. Vou repetir: toda vez que usa um `new` um objeto completamente novo é criado e ocupará espaço na memória por si próprio.

Comment: Enquanto getValues();  Enquanto a instancia não deixar de utiliza-los os objetos permanecerarm no Heap, porém cada objeto do for vão ser removido pela GC caso o ciclo deles termine. A melhor forma de ver onde ta causando a  lentindão é usando um profile.

Comment: Eu tinha entendido que zerava e depois criava um novo e que a alternativa seria a de "trocar todos os seus dados"(reaproveitar o objecto).