# O Garbage Collector remove todos objetos ou somente os que não tem referência?

Tags: java, memória, garbage-collector

Em uma aplicação Java há objetos que não estão sendo usados, dentre esses objetos, há os que possuem e não referência. Como o *Garbage Collector* lida com isso? Ele remove todos ou somente os que não tem referência?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata): [O que é Garbage Collector e como ele funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255769/o-que-%C3%A9-garbage-collector-e-como-ele-funciona)

Comment: Várias possiveis relacionadas(ou duplicatas) [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271845/28595)

Comment: Só os que não tem referência são removidos

Comment: Embora seja um pouco no assunto eu acho que esta dúvida é mais específica e não tem e provavelmente que não terá quando eu terminar lá (preciso retomar a resposta... :))

Comment: @Isac mas entre os objetos não usados, há também os que possuem referência

Comment: Se não está a ser usado mas possui referência significa que ainda pode vir a ser usado, logo não pode ser removido.

Comment: @Isac você disse certo "ainda pode vir a usado", mas eventualmente ele também não pode ser usado

Comment: Eu acho que a sua confusão está precisamente no conceito de "usado". O que é para si um "objeto não usado" ? Consegue exemplificar em código ? A regra para eliminar um objeto de memoria centra-se somente em referências válidas e garantia de não acesso no resto de código a partir de um determinado ponto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A situação é um pouco mais complicada que isso. Claro, o que tem referência nunca é "removido".

Primeiro, vamos entender que o GC do Java usa um mecanismo de *copying*, então objetos "nunca" (na última implementação que eu conheço, isso é detalhe) são removidos, eles são abandonados. O GC copia os que sobrevivem e joga fora os que não precisam mais continuar ativos.

O GC funciona lendo "toda" memória procurando por referência a objetos no *heap*. Claro há otimização para não ler toda ela, depende da geração que está precisando ser limpa.

Hoje Java pode ter referência para objetos fora do *heap*, esses objetos não estão livres do GC, ele podem ser lidos para ver se tem alguma referência para outro objeto dentro dele, mas referências para ele não importam.

Basta ter uma referência para um objeto e ele já é considerado como vivo. E é possível ter falsos positivos. Há heurísticas para evitar ter que analisar todo o grafo de referências. Não pode ter falso negativo, correria o risco de matar algo que ainda precisa continuar. Acontece de alguns objetos sobreviverem mesmo sem ter uma referência. Não costuma ser muito e dura pouco, em geral isso ocorre mais na Gen0 que precisa ser muito rápida.

Na análise o GC olha tudo o que está nas chamadas raízes, por exemplo os registradores e a *stack*. A partir dali ele passa olhar em todos os objetos que ele sabe que está vivo, ou sejam que já tem referências para ele nas raízes. Ele vai montando um grafo, anda por todos os objetos vivos. Os objetos que não possuem referências para ele nunca são analisados para ver se ele possuem referências para outros objetos. Em geral a análise acaba na Gen0. A não ser que dispare um processo de limpeza na Gen1, aí vai até ele. E o mesmo vale para a Gen2.

Vi que o Java fez como .NET, que teria um *heap* de grandes objetos que funciona ligeiramente diferente, mas a base é essa mesmo.

Há um tratamento especial quando um objeto está acima da Gen0. Qualquer tentativa de escrita de referências contidas nesses objetos tem uma barreira de escrita e analisa se precisa tomar alguma ação extra. Se não precisar e rápido, se precisar tem um controle extra a realizar. Entra no *slow path* se a nova referência aponta para um objeto em geração anterior. Esses casos precisam criar uma lista de referências extra para a geração anterior olhar quando vai fazer sua limpeza. Isto é necessário para o GC não ter que analisar a memória toda e pelo menos nas gerações mais baixas que são limpas com mais frequência.

Observando tudo isso, grosso modo, se um objeto não tem uma referência para ele, não é analisado se ele tem referências para outros objetos, e se a única referência para outro objeto era essa que não é mais analisada, ou todas as referências estão em objetos que não mais continuarão ativos, então aquele objeto antes apontado não tem mais referências que o obriguem a se manter vivo, portanto ele provavelmente será abandonado e sua memória não mais será ocupada. Se sobrar uma única referência para um objeto, mesmo que sem querer, ele ainda será mantido e copiado para uma nova arena de memória, provavelmente em uma geração acima do que está, até a Gen2 que atualmente é a última.

Se há uma referência para ele está sendo usado, mesmo que não esteja sendo acessado nesse momento.

Java tem adicionado novos GCs que funcionam de forma um pouco diferente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso acontece em outras tecnologias fora o .NET e o Java?

Comment: Em algumas, nem todas usam GCs e nem todas o mesmo tipo.

Answer (score -1):

O Garbage Collector (GC) é um mecanismo responsável por liberar os objetos alocados na memória heap que não são mais utilizados pelo programa. Esses objetos são considerados "lixo" e o GC os remove da memória para liberar espaço e evitar vazamentos de memória.

O GC remove somente os objetos que não possuem mais referência. Isso significa que, se um objeto é acessado ou referenciado por outro objeto ou variável, ele não será removido pelo GC. Por exemplo, considere o seguinte código em Java:

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = obj1;
```

Nesse caso, o objeto criado na primeira linha é referenciado pelo objeto criado na segunda linha. Portanto, o GC não remove o objeto da memória, pois ele ainda é acessado pelo objeto "obj2".

No entanto, se um objeto não é mais referenciado por nenhuma outra variável ou objeto, ele será considerado pelo GC como lixo e será removido da memória. Por exemplo:

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
obj1 = null;
```

Nesse caso, o objeto criado na primeira linha é referenciado pela variável "obj1", mas na segunda linha "obj1" é redefinida como "null". Isso significa que o objeto não é mais acessado ou referenciado por nenhuma outra variável ou objeto, e portanto pode ser removido pelo GC.

Em resumo, o GC remove da memória os objetos que não são mais acessados ou referenciados por nenhuma outra variável ou objeto. Objetos que ainda são referenciados por outras variáveis ou objetos não são removidos pelo GC.

Comment: Simples e objetivo!

Comment: Só pra ser chato, tem casos em que um objeto pode ser coletado pelo GC, mesmo tendo outro objeto apontando pra ele: é quando ocorre uma [referência cíclica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910194) (A aponta pra B, que aponta pra A, mas nem A nem B estão acessíveis por nenhum ponto do programa)